# Logcat log warning/errors

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

When I connect my galaxy s3 mini via ADB and try debug application with android studio I get endless error/warning messages in logcat, non-stop messages goes like crazy. Is that normal? Usually with emulator I don't get tons of message in logcat. How can I fix this problem? here's how logcat looks like http://pastebin.com/JaVhYaCt or https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHxiu.png

By the way: I still able to test applications.

Comment: What line is spammed? Your link is hard to read

Comment: I updated the question. Screenshot is added.

Comment: it's not helping, I don't know what messages are yours and what are spam. Or it just random and you can't tell by your self.

Comment: There are too many of them. Its hard to tell. for example message like this in the log: 12-22 15:30:01.580    1660-2127/? W/FrameworkListener﹕ Handler 'interface' error (No such device)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that normal?

Yes - the system itself as well as every app uses logging and that's what you're seeing. A bare-bones emulator won't have many apps with receivers and services running so you won't see the same amount of logging.

> How can I fix this problem?

You can't as such but you can reduce it by force closing various apps from "Settings" on the device. Not necessarily a good idea but it's your choice.

You can improve things by using package TAGs in your code and then applying a filter to only show logcat data with your TAGs.

Example...

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected final String TAG = getClass().getName();

}
```

In the above `TAG` will be "com.mycompany.mypackage.MyActivity". Use `protected` as the modifier so any classes which extend `MyActivity` will automatically assign their own class name to `TAG`.

When logging you just use `Log.d(TAG, "Some text");

You then just need to filter on "com.mycompany.mypackage" to only see logging from your own app components.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: android studio provides the same function and don't need to have codes above

Comment: @Jacky : Huh? Do you want to explain that comment further?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer is that is normal to see all this verbose logging (the logcat contains info from everything on the phone, so can get quite verbose).

You can filter what is shown in logcat by using filters.  If using the command line, it might look something like this (don't forget the end S:* - which indicates to 'Silence' everything. A simple tag filter from command line might look like this (show only messages with tags SHOWTAG1, and SHOWTAG2:

```
adb logcat SHOWTAG1:* SHOWTAG2:* S:*
```

The eclipse tooling (and maybe Android Studio, not sure) also has a Logcat viewer, which allows you to apply tags to filter by, or otherwise, use Regex or other filtering mechanisms to modify what is shown.

Bottom line, Logcat is verbose, you will need to filter it specifically to see what you want.