# LogCat shows errors from Android while testing with AVD

Tags: java, android

I have a very basic Android app. When I launch it on an Android Virtual device, and look at LogCat I see a number of errors and warnings - largely not from my application code, from `com.android.*` and `system_process`

For example

```
05-12 14:45:05.554: E/ActivityThread(392): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
05-12 14:45:05.564: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(392): Could not find a dictionary pack
05-12 14:45:06.163: W/ContextImpl(997): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2376 
05-12 14:52:06.206: E/ThrottleService(300): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-12 15:11:42.594: E/Trace(2448): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-12 15:11:42.944: E/Trace(2464): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-12 15:11:43.283: E/ActivityThread(2464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-12 15:11:43.293: E/ActivityThread(2464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-12 15:11:43.424: E/DictionaryBackupAgent(455): Couldn't read from the cursor
```

So here's my question: Are these normal or is there some real information there I need to pay attention to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most are 'Normal' in the sense that every device (emulator or physical) constantly outputs errors and warnings.

Here is another post you may want to reference.
[Logcat log warning/errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729853/logcat-log-warning-errors)